# Fanfic where Hermione leaves the Wizarding World, pregnant with Harry's baby, and comes back when their son starts his first year

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I think it's about 18 chapters long. I could be wrong, but the gist was that Hermione got pregnant during the war and was waiting to tell Harry after they'd defeated Voldemort, because she didn't want to pressure him.

Anyways, fast forward to after the war, she was coming around to tell him when she saw Harry and Ginny lip-locking on the school field; needless to say, she left that night and never looked back.

The Wizarding World never stopped looking for her, spearheaded by Harry, who kept looking for her even after everyone else gave up. Eleven years later, Hermione came back with a son and she uses her mother's maiden name and goes by Hermione Watson instead of Hermione Granger.

Harry runs a top-secret wizarding operation and was given the opportunity to work for the school. He took it and unknowingly becomes close with his son. Hermione was kidnapped, then Harry rescued her and was furious that she kept his son away from him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are you looking to identify a fanfic here? If so, in roughly which year did you read it?

Comment: For the time being, I've edited your question based on the presumption that you're looking for a fanfic, but do correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

As per [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/HPharmony/comments/azq937/lost_fic_help/), found via a search for `fanfic hermione "harry's son"`, might this be "[Sempre Fidelis](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/13055229/1/)" by Untold Harmony?

> She left years ago after he saved the wizarding world from the hands of Voldemort. She never thought she would be back again... until her son got his letter to Hogwarts.

She's hiding under the name of Jane Watson. Her son is named James. And your memory is correct about the Quidditch pitch.

> Hermione told herself she would tell Harry of their baby the day after The Defeat. But then she found him at the ruined Quidditch pitch with his lips locked with Ginny Weasley and their arms wrapped tight around one other.

It looks like it ceased updating in 2020 with 17 chapters.